# How to pass tablename as parameter to Bigquery command line in shell script

Tags: shell, google-bigquery

```
#creating tables with schema only:

for f in $list;              
do           
echo "event name :::::$f"      
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --destination_table dataset_name.$f  'select * from `project_id.dataset_name.$f` where 1=2'   
done
```

The query statement is not considering `$f` as a parameter in select statement.

Comment: You're using single quotes around the SQL statement. Use double quotes and your variables will interpolate: `"select * from project_id.dataset_name.$f where 1=2"`

Comment: Replaced single quotes by double quotes as suggested but it is throwing error as          bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --destination_table dataset_name.$f  'select * from `project_id.dataset_name.$f` where 1=2'

Comment: bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --destination_table dataset_name.$f  "select * from `project_id.dataset_name.$f` where 1=2"          Syntax error: Unexpected keyword WHERE at [1:16]

Comment: Maybe your shell interprets the backticks (``) around `project_id.dataset_name.$f` as a subcommand. Try leaving them out or quoting them by using a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of the ticks [ ' ] .

Here you have a working code (I used numbers):

```
for i in {1..3}
do
echo "TABLE $i"
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select * from `<project>.<database>.'$i'`'
done
```

See how I separated the parameter `$i` with ticks [ ' ]. For your case it should be:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --destination_table dataset_name.$f  'select * from `project_id.dataset_name.'$f'` where 1=2'
```